# how to convert json data in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, json

I am getting json data from service. this is my json data:

```
[
 {
  "id":"1",
  "body":"sample text",
  "read":"true",
  "checked":"true"
 },
 {
  "id":"2",
  "body":"sample text",
  "read":"true",
  "checked":"false"
 }
]
```

I want to read it as id=2,read=true , how to convert this json string format to actual datatype.

Comment: what do you mean by datatype?

Comment: You should already be able to access it like that.  Note that you have an array, so you'd need to do data[0].id = 2;

Comment: data type means I am trying to check boolean values true or false in my controller but they are coming like "true" "false" and id are "1" .

Comment: what do you mean by actual data type. Can you please tell me what is the end product that you want. You want to display the data or you want to do some computations on them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through your array and process the boolean values that are currently represented as text. In the example below, I've used JSON.parse to process the boolean text and then saved the result back to the read variable. Save applies to id but I've gone for parseInt in this case.

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

//example mock http call
function getHttpData() {
  return [{
    "id": "1",
    "body": "sample text",
    "read": "false",
    "checked": "true"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "body": "sample text",
    "read": "true",
    "checked": "false"
  }];
}

function getData() {
  var data = getHttpData();

  //process array as required
  data.forEach(function(value) {
    value.id = parseInt(value.id);
    value.read = JSON.parse(value.read);
  });

  return data;
}

$scope.data = getData();
});
```

Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/tmakin/cvzc4mks/5/

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass your JSON string to the [JSON.parse() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). That will return a JavaScript object that you can use normally.